# How do I create an indexes for "date"?

Tags: mongodb

How do I create an indexes for "date"?

CentOS7, MongoDB server version: 3.4.2

```
db.animals.createIndex('date')
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'key' must be an object, but got string",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}

db.animals.find({}, {date: 1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : 3477, "date" : ISODate("2016-12-22T09:38:59Z") }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can create simple index on key `date` using:

```
Ascending order: db.animals.createIndex({'date':1})

Descending order: db.animals.createIndex({'date':-1})
```

You may need to take a look at [indexing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) doc before adding indexes

Comment: when should i use 1 rather than -1?

Answer (score 8):

for single field you don't need to reverse the index as mongodb can use the index in either direction. It should only matter when you have a compound index and you have a sort going in different directions.

Comment: Then what is the point of specifying `1` or `-1` ?