# Mongodb find query running long time

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am using mongodb latest version 3.4.10. i have collection name called transaction with 14000 records. the below query i ran it taking to complete 10sec.

command : db.transaction.find({mcCreatedTime : { $gte:ISODate("2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte:ISODate("2017-11-02T23:59:59.000Z")}})

It will return expected record with taking long time around 10 sec.  I need to complete the query within msec.

I am using windows 8.1 and 4GB of RAM and 500GB hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an index as:

```
db.transaction.createIndex({mcCreatedTime:1}, {background:true})
```

You need to take a look at [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to check why your query is slow.

Comment: i have created index. but no luck. it's took 10sec to complete

Comment: how much data you have? What does the explain command return?

Comment: the query is return correct output 6301 records . in my transaction collection it have 14000 records is there.

Comment: Explain look like the query using IXSCAN .."executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 6301,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 15,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 6301,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 6301,

Comment: Your query takes only 15ms to execute in DB to execute :)

Comment: Ohh. i am running a query in robomongo.

Comment: Maybe it look like robomongo issue?

Comment: I don't know , why robomongo takes more time??

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get faster query results in a database management system is to build indexes.

Try creating an index on `mcCreatedTime` field to make it return results faster.

Ascending order: `db.transaction.createIndex({'mcCreatedTime':1})` should be able to create the required index.

[Mongo DB Index Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42887646/1889046)

Comment: Index created. but the query is result is slow

Comment: @K.Boopathi17  can you check if you have implemented both ascending and descending indexes on date column, as both are required for faster results when doing sorting or range search. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330373/1889046