# 30-oct-2018 00:00:00 change string to iso date in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with string filed which has data like '30-oct-2018 00:00:00'
How can i update this filed datatype to Date with out changing its value.
ie; ISODate("2018-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. "update" is the same as "change" Either you want to update or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887627/how-do-i-create-an-indexes-for-date

Answer (score 0):

You should never store date /time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Natively MongoDB does not support month names, you have to use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/)  statement with 12 branches.

Or use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to convert. But then you need to use it in a `forEach` line by line